# Kill vncserver But leave session open

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, vnc

My problem is, I want to start a process which I can only starty by `UI` and then stop the `VNC` session.

By stoping the `vncserver` it kills my sub processes as well. For security reasons I don't want to leave a server with only 8 characters password.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i learned that vnc is not the only free option for remote destop under linux. there is xrdp as well. this actually worked even better and users can log in with their accounts.

```
apt-get install xrdp
```